# Unwanted JPanel border in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to fill JFrame with a JPanel and colour that JPanel, but for some reason I get a border on the bottom right edges.

My code:

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

    public MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.init();
    }

    public void init()
    {
        this.setSize(300,400);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setContentPane(myPanel);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        myPanel.paintComponents(g);
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel
    {
        @Override
        public void paintComponents(Graphics g)
        {
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

Shows:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're short-circuiting the paint chain with this method

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    myPanel.paintComponents(g);
}
```

This isnt really doing anything useful so you can remove it. Also you need to override `paintComponent` rather than `paintComponents` in `MyPanel`

```
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
```

Aside:

- You could have simply created a panel and called `setBackground` to get this functionality

Comment: But if I take that out nothing will be painted!